# How do I handle ajax authentication after initial Login with Shiro

Tags: ajax, authentication, single-page-application, shiro

I have implemented the usual username/password login process with Shiro for my single page webapp which will submit the username and password over https in production. I use a REST back end rather than a typical MVC framework of any sort to facilitate my SPA. Typically with a REST API a BasicAuth is used to log in, and in response if successful an encrypted token is returned either as a cookie or a response header. Subsequent calls would return the cookie or header to avoid having to resend username and password. Usually the token is an ecnrypted username possibly with some other info that can be derived on the server side either as a session token or something else.

Anyway, as I said I am using Shiro and I understand Shiro can use multiple realms for authentication and authorization. What I am trying to do for my web site is require the initial username/password login, then after a user is logged in, somehow avoid the Shiro UsernamePassword authentication process and instead use the token check process.

I think the right way is to provide my own custom authentication realm and credentials matcher.. and I have a public domain SHA256 salted password bit of code that stores the salt, iterations and password in one string that I'd like to use. What I am not sure of is how to configure the shiro.ini... do I need to provide two custom classes, one for my own username/password for initial login, then another for my token authentication? Or can I utilize the built-in shiro usernamePassword, and will it's rememberMe feature be good enough in jquery $.ajax() calls? Perhaps I can use the Shiro implementation but also need to attach the shiro rememberMe cookie to all my $.ajax() calls?

Just a little confused really on the best approach to provide good username/password initial login and subsequent calls without needing to resent username/password... and to support session invalidation and logout functionality.

Another thought is to not use Shiro, instead use my own servlet filter to check for the initial login, if authenticated, return the response header (or cookie) myself with my own encrypted token that I keep in HttpSession or in a database back end for the duration of the session, and make sure in my jquery ajax that after each response to look for the token, and resend it in the subsequent requests.

Thanks

Comment: Can you shorten your question? As soon as a user ist authenticated, a cookie in the clients browser is set. This cookie authenticates all following requests - even ajax reqiests... As long as the http-only flag isn't set...

Comment: Why shorten? Wanted to provide enough details to get the point across to obtain a good answer. I realize this reply is 4 years later.. but too often too much detail is left out so it results in lots of back and forth questions to get all the details. I prefer to put it all out there up front. If its too much to read, no problem..move along. I understand lengthy questions/responses are not for everyone. But it does save on a lot of back and forth, and on a forum like this, it should be commended to avoid lots of responses that are seeking more details.